# Compatibility issues using Jelly ORM with Kohana 3.2, time to move on?

Tags: kohana-3, jelly

I like Jelly ORM and I want to use it with Kohana 3.2. However, I'm receiving different errors as I try its various methods and actions.

I see the last update to Jelly ORM was more than year ago on github.

Should we say "Goodbye" to it?

Answer (score 0):

The original author of Jelly stopped active development before Kohana 3.1 was released. From that point, someone else [forked Jelly](https://github.com/creatoro/kohana-jelly-for-Kohana-3.1/) and upgraded the unstable branch to Kohana 3.1. I don't know the current state of this fork. But upgrading that one for Kohana 3.2 shouldn't be too much work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working now: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9833/jelly-for-kohana-3.2-auth-driver